# SMB performance over VPN (WAN)

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, smb

I'm currently trying to make a few SMB fileshares available to users via VPN. Connectivity and network speeds over VPN are fast and reliable and can saturate the available bandwidth (I picked Wireguard for the initial configuration).

However, even with decent connectivity (200 MBits down, 50 Mbits up, 20ms latency) accessing files on the fileshare does not work reliably. Ofter the windows explorer completely freezes and has to be restart.

Are there any settings/configurations either client or server-side that can be made to improve SMB performance? (e.g. caching, etc.)

I'm using Windows 10/11 on the clients and Windows Server 2019 on the server